# How to remove content after a specific character or symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my example.

```
/^[Today]*/ig
```

I want to remove every words after the last /  to be come the sample at below. I'm not sure will have how many slash in the real data.

```
/^[Today]*/
```

Comment: show the example string and output

Comment: This is a duplicate. Search stackoverflow and there are a lot of answers to this question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "/^[Today]*/ig";
var substring = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Result: `/^[Today]*/`